# Reactstrap Card component throws error

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

The issue is with the reactstrap cards: https://reactstrap.github.io/components/card/

Using reactstrap components like Card, etc is not working.

**Component: Version I**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, Button, CardImg, CardTitle, CardText, CardDeck, CardSubtitle, CardBody } from 'reactstrap';

class MoviesIndex extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <CardDeck>
                <Card>
                    <CardImg top width="100%" src="" alt="Movie Poster" />
                </Card>
            </CardDeck>
        );
    }
}

export default MoviesIndex;
```

**Output:** *It works fine without any errors.

---

But when I try to use the rest of the components from reactstrap. It throws errors on console.

**Component: Version II**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, Button, CardImg, CardTitle, CardText, CardDeck, CardSubtitle, CardBody } from 'reactstrap';

class MoviesIndex extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <CardDeck>
                <Card>
                    <CardImg top width="100%" src="" alt="Movie Poster" />
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardTitle>Card title</CardTitle>
                        <CardSubtitle>Card subtitle</CardSubtitle>
                        <CardText>This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</CardText>
                        <Button>Button</Button>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            </CardDeck>
        );
    }
}

export default MoviesIndex;
```

**Output:**
[image]

---

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^8.1.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.2.1",
    "reactstrap": "^4.8.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3"
  }
}
```

I am not able to debug this issue. Please help! TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The components such as `CardBody`, etc are not available in v4.8.0.

Upgrading to latest release (reactstrap v5.0.0-alpha.4) resolves this issue!

`npm install --save reactstrap@5.0.0-alpha.4`

Refer to the issue that I created on reactstrap@github for more details:
https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/730

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a typo here:

```
renderMovies() {
        return _.map(this.props.movies, movie => {
```

Missing `)`

Try

```
_.map(this.props.movies, movie) => {
```

If that doesn't do it, put `console.log()` after everything to see where it becomes `undefined`.

This type of error usually results from something not being exported correctly or something being null/undefined due to data missing, etc.

This is a good opportunity for me to recommend using ES Lint, so you can gain extra help 24/7 from the passive display of errors. Check it out if you aren't using it. It's absolutely worth looking into and using.

I won't recommend any specific linting configs in here. That is out of scope of this help. ES Lint will underline code errors such as the missing `)` with a red underline, so you will experience less of this kind of thing :)

Comment: There is no missing ')'. That's second argument to the lodash map function. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map

Comment: As already mentioned, the first version of the component is already working! There doesn't seem like a scope to put a console.log anywhere since the problem seems to be with the 'Card' reactstrap component or elsewhere@